# Working with list of tuples: calculating number of items

Tags: c#, tuples

I have the following code working with Tuples. Input is list of items, output is list of tuples and we need to calculate number of items for each date basically.

```
List<Tuple<DateTime, int>> list = new List<Tuple<DateTime, int>>();
foreach (ItemClass item in items)
{
    foreach(Tuple<DateTime, int> tuple in list)
    {
         if (tuple.Item1 == item.date)
         {
              tuple.Item2++;
              continue;
          }
    }
    list.Add(Tuple.Create<DateTime, int>(item.date, 1)); 
}
```

This code currently doesn't compile because `Item2` is read-only, the question is how to make it work?

Earlier this worked with the `Dictionary` but I had to remove it because it was not acceptable for outer code to work with the `Dictionary`.

Comment: You're creating a new list of tuples then iterating an empty collection? That doesn't make any sense. And what is `tu.date`, where did that come from?

Comment: Tuples are immutable by design, so rewrite it using Dictionary (or List<KeyValuePair>).

Comment: Can you not introduce a new class with a DateTime property and an int property? Not only do you then solve your immutability problem but you also get more readable code.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov It was a misprint item.date, fixed now, items are not empty collection and tuples are filled during execution of this function

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tuples are not intended for use in scenarios where mutability is required. You could make your own class that combines a `DateTime` with a mutable integer counter, but you can also do it with LINQ, converting to a list of tuples at the very end:

```
var list = items
    .GroupBy(item => item.date)
    .Select(g => Tuple.Create(g.Key, g.Count()))
    .ToList();
```

The above code creates a group for each date, and then produces tuples only when the final counts of items in each group are known.

Answer (score 4):

Try using Linq, `GroupBy()`to group by date, then use `Select()` and create a tuple for each group and finally convert to a list using `ToList()`. Something like

```
var result = items.GroupBy(x => x.Date)
                  .Select(x => Tuple.Create(x.Key, x.Count()))
                  .ToList();
```

Comment: You forgot to assign the `List` to a value.

Answer (score -1):

I'm assuming because it's read only it already has a property, I think I've used tuple before so yeah, it probably does.

maybe you can't edit it because you can edit iterators in the Foreach() loop, perhaps experiment with another kind of loop.

OR

Set the item2 object to an object outside of the current loop and use that instead of the iterator.